# -jailshell: d-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, redhat, glibc

I'm trying to install an executable but it gives me the error `-jailshell: d-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`, I have already checked if I have the glib 32-bit version with the command `rpm -qf /lib/ld-linux.so.2` and `rpm -qa | grep glibc | grep i686` and it seems to be ok (it prints me `glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.i686`).

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to install an executable but it gives me the error

This executable is *corrupt*.

It is trying to use `d-linux-x86-64.so.2` as an interpreter, and such a file doesn't exist (nor should it exist) on your machine.

Chances are this executable was transferred over FTP in `ASCII` mode, or corrupted in some other way.

> I have already checked if I have the glib 32-bit version

That is irrelevant: the binary you are trying to build is a 64-bit binary.

Also, there is a difference between glib and glibc.